# Connect desktop to router for network access without cable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, desktop-computer

Is there a way to connect a pc (desktop) to a router for internet access without a cable?
I think that some kind of usb adapter to connect over wifi is possible but I don't know what is the term I am looking for to search for this

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a *USB WLAN adapter*.

[image: WLAN USB adapter]

Here are also PCI/PCI-E cards that plug into an available slot inside your computer.

[image]

All such adapters share the common name *WLAN adapter* (Wireless Local Area Network).

Comment: For the `USB WLAN adapter` I just attach it as a usb stick right?

Comment: Yes, you attach the adapter just as any USB key.